# Acknowledge and Reload PartialView with Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I am new to MVC3 and Razor.

I have an "attention banner" on the master page as a Partial View that I want to "acknowledge" with a click on a link to close the banner (without reloading the page).  I believe I need to use jQuery and an Ajax call, but I just can't seem to find the right combination.

Here is part of my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<section id="main">
    <span id="attentionBar">@{ Html.RenderPartial("_AttentionBarPartial"); }</span>
    @RenderBody()
</section>
```

This is my Partial View (just using Session as a shortcut for now to get it to work).  I'm not sure what to use as the "link" to reload the view:

```
    @{ this.Layout = null;}
    @if(! String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Session["Attention"].ToString()))
    {    
        <div class="attentionPanel">
            <span class="attentionLabel">Attention</span>
            @Session["Attention"].ToString()
            <span class="attentionLabel">
@*   WHAT DO I PUT HERE *@
                @Ajax.ActionLink("X", "AcknowledgeAttentionBar", "Home", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId="attentionPanel", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace })
            </span>              
        </div>
    }
```

Here is my Home controller.  Again, I am not sure that the code is quite correct, but essentially I will clear out the condition that shows the attention banner.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Home Controller Updated At " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
            + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult AcknowledgeAttentionBar()
    {
        Session["Attention"] = String.Empty;
        return PartialView("_AttentionBarPartial");
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen your design. BUT, attention banners are rarely a good design component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Make sure you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page in order for `Ajax.ActionLink` helper to work and send an AJAX request when the link is clicked instead of a normal redirect:

   ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. In your `AjaxOptions` you have specified `UpdateTargetId="attentionPanel"` but there's no element in your markup with `id="attentionPanel"`. You have a div with `class="attentionPanel"` but that's not the same thing. On the other hand you have wrapped your banner in a `<span id="attentionBar">`, so you probably meant `UpdateTargetId="attentionBar"`.

Comment: Thanks - that did it.  #1 was the big thing I was missing, and #2 was just me worrying too much about the big picture and missing simple details.